# urllib.urlretrieve() cannot download the file

Tags: python

Hi there's a button in the web, if you click it, it'll download a file.

Say the corresponding url is like this
http://www.mydata.com/data/filedownload.aspx?e=MyArgu1&k=kfhk22wykq

If i put this url in the address bar in the browser, it can download the file as well properly.

Now i do this in the python,

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "myData.csv")
```

The csv file is empty. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible with every website. If a link has a token then python is unlikely to be able to use the link as it is tied to your browser.

Comment: Even though i'm not quite understand, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why someone gives me "-1", can you clearly explain anything wrong with my question ? i don't understand ppl these day.

Comment: ＠SiegfriedWinterstein how can i fix this in python please？

Comment: The problem is your link i think. Some websites use tokens in the link and don't allow you to share that link with other people. Your link only works for your browser and can't be used in anything else. I dont know if its fixable or something you can do with Python.

Comment: ＠SiegfriedWinterstein，thanks very much for the info !